# Adding time to DateTime is giving an error

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to add time and days to a couple DateTime values in the add_2_calendar flutter package. This is the documentation for the package: https://pub.dev/packages/add_2_calendar/example

Here is the code I am trying to implement:

```
class AddEventsToAllCalendars {

  addEvent(Events event) {
    Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(buildEvent(event));
  }

  Event buildEvent(Events event) {
    int eventRecurrenceEndDate = event.eventDate!.difference(event.eventDate!).inDays;

    Frequency freq = Frequency.daily;

    if (event.frequency == 'daily') {
      freq = Frequency.daily;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'weekly') {
      freq = Frequency.weekly;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'monthly') {
      freq = Frequency.monthly;
    } else {
      freq = Frequency.yearly;
    }

    return Event(
      title: event.eventName!,
      description: event.eventDescription,
      location: event.location,
      startDate: event.eventStartTime!,
      endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(const Duration(minutes: int.parse(event.eventDuration!))),  <<< ERROR HERE
      allDay: event.allDay,

      androidParams: const AndroidParams(
        emailInvites: ["test@gmail.com"],
      ),
      recurrence:  Recurrence(
        frequency: freq,
        endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(const Duration(days: event.recurrenceEndDate.difference(event.eventDate).inDays)), <<<  ERROR HERE
    );
  }
```

I am getting an error that I don't know how to fix. Here is the error message:

```
Evaluation of this constant expression throws an exception.dart(const_eval_throws_exception)
Duration Duration({
  int days = 0,
  int hours = 0,
  int minutes = 0,
  int seconds = 0,
  int milliseconds = 0,
  int microseconds = 0,
})
```

I think I am providing integers for the .add in both lines of code so what am I doing wrong here?
Thanks for your help

Comment: Can you try removing const from here 

endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(event.eventDuration!)))

Same at the last third line 

endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(days: event.recurrenceEndDate.difference(event.eventDate).inDays)),

Comment: Thanks. I thought I had tried that but I guess not. It worked.

Comment: Glad to know that! I added a answer to help future viewers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove constants as by removing the const keyword, you allow the Duration objects to be created at runtime, resolving the constant expression evaluation error.
So endDate attribute should be

```
endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(minutes:int.parse(event.eventDuration!)))
```

and

```
endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(days: event.recurrenceEndDate.difference(event.eventDate).inDays))
```

So the complete answer will be -

```
class AddEventsToAllCalendars {

  addEvent(Events event) {
    Add2Calendar.addEvent2Cal(buildEvent(event));
  }

  Event buildEvent(Events event) {
    int eventRecurrenceEndDate = event.eventDate!.difference(event.eventDate!).inDays;

    Frequency freq = Frequency.daily;

    if (event.frequency == 'daily') {
      freq = Frequency.daily;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'weekly') {
      freq = Frequency.weekly;
    } else if (event.frequency == 'monthly') {
      freq = Frequency.monthly;
    } else {
      freq = Frequency.yearly;
    }

    return Event(
      title: event.eventName!,
      description: event.eventDescription,
      location: event.location,
      startDate: event.eventStartTime!,
      endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(minutes: int.parse(event.eventDuration!))),  //Removed const here
      allDay: event.allDay,

      androidParams: const AndroidParams(
        emailInvites: ["test@gmail.com"],
      ),
      recurrence:  Recurrence(
        frequency: freq,
        endDate: event.eventStartTime!.add(Duration(days: event.recurrenceEndDate.difference(event.eventDate).inDays)), //Removed Const here
    );
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `const` for value that is calculated.